# Find location of Latex's included style files

Tags: include

I need to find the dependency files for a certain LaTeX report, which includes some files not in the current directory (I assume it finds these on the system path). Currently, I've put a template on ShareLatex.com, but it won't compile as these are missing. How might I find these files?

E.g. In the template it has \usepackage {graphicx}, and on this line the compiler says LaTeX Error: File `a4-mancs.sty' not found.

Thanks for your help. Let me know if anything needs clarifying, as I'm a bit confused myself.

Comment: Adding `\listfiles` to your preamble on the computer that compiles the project will list all the files included and their locations. From there you can copy-and-paste them to ShareLaTeX.

Comment: @Werner `\listfiles` doesn't show the path but that is always shown in the log anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True. `\listfiles` only show the file and a short description.

Comment: every time tex includes a file it shows the file path used both on the terminal and in the log,  so if your file works locally the log will show something like `(/usr/local/tex/latex.a4-mancs.sty` or whatever the path is.

Comment: you can't possibly want `a4-mancs.sty` in any real document written this century, a better alternative would be just update the document not to use it. (I can speak with some authority on that, as I assume it's `https://github.com/taxomania/Project-Report/blob/master/a4-mancs.sty#L6` (note the initials:-)

Comment: The error has nothing to do with `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: @cfr Sorry for the confusion. I mentioned grahpicx due to this error on sharelatex. Not sure why exactly it appears on this usepackage line. Possibly an unrelated issue? [Error here](http://i.imgur.com/tUK16FE.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are `404` the initials?

Comment: @ginister presumably you were loading a4-mancs on the previous line, so it was the line with \usepackage{graphicx} that tex reached by the time it knew something was wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see query in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343732/find-location-of-latexs-included-style-files/343758?noredirect=1#comment843741_343758. I got pinged, but it is addressed to you, too. And you should be better able to answer ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, yes it was as simple as looking at the terminal output when calling latex on the .tex file. And regarding a4-mancs.sty, it's being used for my 3rd year project report as it is in that link. I think I'd probably be best suited making sure it adheres to my university's expectations :) But thanks for the tip!

Comment: The problem is probably on the previous line. TeX just doesn't realise until this line. You really don't want to use `a4-mancs.sty`. It can't be required to use that. Just use `geometry` with appropriate settings instead.

Comment: @cfr and David: Thanks for your help. And you are indeed correct about it being the previous line - I wasn't aware that was how it reported errors so thank you. LaTeX isn't one of my strong suits but out of curiosity what is bad about the a4-mancs.sty file other than it being well out of date?